# Clicking textarea hides label value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to delete the label when I click into the textarea?

http://jsfiddle.net/1smvym84/4/

HTML:

```
<li id='field_1_9' class='gfield' >
    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_9'>Place this inside the textarea</label>
    <div class='ginput_container'>
        <textarea name='input_9' id='input_1_9' class='textarea medium' tabindex='8'   rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.textarea').text($('.gfield_label').text());
    $('.gfield_label').remove();
});
```

Many thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? You haven't posted a click event.

Comment: Why not use a placeholder?

Comment: your label is already deleted in your `ready` function! And indeed, look into setting it as placeholder with `attr` in stead of setting it as content with `text`

Comment: What is the use case for this kind of behaviour? What is the benefit, especially for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete it on focus:

```
$("#input_1_9").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent("div").prev("label").remove();
});
```

Comment: Note that this somewhat brittle, as it is bound to the DOM structure of the example, and may have unexpected behavior if that changes. Using the `for` attribute may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is HTML's placeholder attribute:

```
<textarea name="input_9" id="input_1_9" class="textarea medium" tabindex="8" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Your text goes here"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you will use placeholders. Like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="Place this inside the textarea"></textarea>
```

But, if you want do it in JS it will be like this:

```
$('.textarea').on('click', function() {
$('.gfield_label').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //work for all elements which have the css class textarea
  $('.textarea').click(function(){
      $('.textarea').val($('.gfield_label').html());
      //if you want to remove all elements having gfield_label css class
      $('.gfield_label').remove();
  });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="gfield_label">this is label</label>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to delete it when entering then add it back if nothing is written. There are 2 ways to accomplish this:

The HTML5 way:http://jsfiddle.net/1smvym84/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var placeholderText = $('.gfield_label').text();
   $('.textarea').attr("placeholder",placeholderText);
   $('.gfield_label').remove();
});
```

The jQuery way: http://jsfiddle.net/1smvym84/7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var placeholderText = $('.gfield_label').text();
   $('.textarea').text(placeholderText);
    $('.gfield_label').remove();

    $('.textarea').focus(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === placeholderText){
            $(this).text("");
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === ""){
            $(this).text(placeholderText);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `for` attribute on the labels consistently, looking up the appropriate label to delete should be fairly easy:

```js
$('.textarea').on("focus", function() {
  var areaId = $(this).attr("id");
  var areaLabel = $("label[for='" + areaId + "']");
  
  // Get the content from the label
  $(this).text(areaLabel.text());
  
  // Remove the label
  areaLabel.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_9'>Place this inside the textarea</label>
<div class='ginput_container'>
  <textarea name='input_9' id='input_1_9' class='textarea medium' tabindex='8' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
</div>
```